# Acceptable rate of http requests

Tags: objective-c, http, macos, denial-of-service

I want to add a feature to my applications which parses an HTML page and jumps out to each `<a href="http:\\foo" >` in turn.

Im gathering title,description and keywords off each page load and loading nothing else and dont intend to allow the jump to be more than one in depth.

This in itself is a trivial application of `NSURLDownload` and `NSXMLDocument` but what I want to know...

Is there an acceptable rate of requests that wont make my app look like a DOS event as if I just flow out the child requests at the rate I parse them from the parent page then I suspect this will very rapidly get detected as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should conform to [the robots exclusion protocol](http://www.robotstxt.org/).  RFC 2616 specifies a limit of 2 concurrent requests per hostname, however modern browsers go past this and this part of the specification is likely to be revised in accordance.  It's likely that `NSURLConnection` will use a connection limit internally anyway, but you should check this.